# Optimizing pulp solver constraint building time

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

So basically I have a problem that usually has a lot of constraints(4-5 stations x 720 timeslots x 200+ object) and I have constraints in which time slots the objects are assignable, they are assignable to only one station and so on and so on.

My question is there a way to speed up the way I build the constraints? Every time a new object is added I need to re-recreate the whole solution with all of the constraints and adding in all of the constraints + solving the task usually takes ~1.20min when I have a couple of stations and ~300 objects but I want to get that down as the problem gets re-created often.

What I can add as additional requirement are:

- I don't want to lose any of the constraints soo far.
- I thought about a warm start but I don't see that working as adding a new object would effect all of the previous constraints + some of the previous object might have already been removed so we might want to drop them from the solution as well
- I tried adding some threads to the solver, and tried a couple of different solvers but the main slow down is adding the vast amount of constraints so that didn't improve the speed by any significant amount.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.